# Fulltext search that isn't exact match

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL-table called "customers1" running engine MyISAM. I've created a full text index on the columns name,adress and zip. Now one of the customers in that table is me. I spell my name "Gildebrand". Now i can't expect that the users can spell my name correctly, many might write "Glidebrant", but still want to find my. How could i do that search in SQL?

If i run the following query right now

```
SELECT * FROM customers1 WHERE MATCH(name,adress,zip) AGAINST('Gildebrand')
```

It finds me, of course. But if i misspell, "Glidebrand", it doesn't find me. What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a generic search similar to yours. Here's basically what I do:

```
SELECT * FROM customers1 WHERE MATCH(name,adress,zip) AGAINST('?')
UNION
SELECT * FROM customers1 WHERE name LIKE ('?%')
```

This allows the user to just enter a prefix also.

If the user realizes they can't spell your name, but they're sure it starts with `Gil`, then they can just type that.

You can add additional UNION clauses if you want to support prefixes on other columns too.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the closest you can get from such a result if by using `SOUNDEX()` http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-soundex-function.php